# How to round a value in Twig

Tags: twig, template-engine

I want to round a value in Twig.

Example: I want to display `80.5555` as `80.55`.

Can any one suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use the [format](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/filters/format.html) filter for that:

```
{{ '%.2f'|format(80.5555) }}
```

But note that it will round it to `80.56`.

Answer (score 32):

```
{{ 80.5555 | number_format(2) }}
```

Here is the documentation [number_format](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/filters/number_format.html)

Answer (score 3):

Twig documentation says that there's a filter for this task, since 1.15.0:

just write  `{{80.5555|round}}`

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/filters/round.html