# Rounding numbers in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Does someone know how to round down numbers in Twig to the nearest whole number?

Ex : 2.6 => 2

I tried to use `|number_format` but it doesn't round down them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a value in Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991157/how-to-round-a-value-in-twig)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow the instructions on [this page](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/advanced.html#filters) to create your own filter:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter('floor', new Twig_Filter_Function('floor'));
```

Then in your template:

```
{{ myNumber|floor }}
```

Answer (score 25):

@olivierw's answer is correct, but there's another trick you can use. Twig does have [`//`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/templates.html#math) operator which floors down result of division. You can use it as `{{ variable // 1 }}` which equals to `intval(floor(variable))`.

Comment: This won't work if `variable` is negative: `{{ -3.6 // 1 }}` will return -4.

Answer (score 6):

Since twig 1.15, you can use round filter.

```
{{ 2.6|round(0, 'floor') }}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/filters/round.html